# Ansible - Configuring AWS EC2 instance after it's created

Tags: ansible

I've got an Ansible playbook that creates an AWS EC2 instance through a CloudFormation template. After it's created I would like to configure it also through Ansible.

Here is what I have now:

```
---
- name: Create Amazon Linux Instance
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
  - config.yml

  tasks:
  - name: Create CloudFormation Stack
    cloudformation:
      stack_name: "{{ stack_name }}"
      state: present
      template: basic-ec2-stack.json
      template_parameters:
        KeyName: "{{ key_name }}"
        VpcId: "{{ vpc_id }}"
        SubnetId: "{{ subnet_id }}"
        ...
    register: stack

  # The new instance name is in stack.stack_outputs.DnsName ...
  - debug: var=stack.stack_outputs.DnsName
```

Now what? How can I run the rest of the playbook against the newly created host?

For example I would like to create user 'blah' but not on the localhost (against which the cloudformation module is running) but obviously on the new EC2 instance. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add the instance to a group with [add_host](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html) and create an in memory inventory.

```
   - name: Add instance  to host group
     add_host: hostname={{ item.DnsName }} groups=cloud_formation
     with_items: stack.stack_outputs

   - name: Wait for SSH to come up
     wait_for: host={{ item.DnsName }} port=22 delay=60 timeout=320 state=started
     with_items: stack.stack_outputs

   - name: Run your play
     hosts: cloud_formation
     ----- your play here -------
```